# How to capture group index for points with the same position?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have bunch of points and they are overlapping (most common is 4 at the same coordinate).
Is there a way to assign group index to all points sharing the same location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sample the nearest index from a branch in which you have merged points by distance.  Here ID is set, but you could just capture, instead:

[image]

Then all vertices less than `Distance` apart will share the same `ID`

(You could capture *Accumulate Field* > 'Total' with `1` as the field value, using `ID` as 'Group Index', to separate coincident points from the others)

Comment: Nice trick! I was thinking using modulo to define a unique integer for each cell of a 3D grid, but using a 32 bit integer that gives a resolution of $11×11×10$ bits or $2048×2048×1024$ grid cells. For 2 m × 2m × 1 m space a grid cell of 1 mm, not terrible but much worse as the space increases…

Comment: @Markus .. and you've got the problem of same-cell-but-not-closest? This one, once again, relying on in-house BVH..

Comment: I have no problem, just saying I would solve this in a worse way. One could improve the cells algorithm to just list the cells used and then sort them, but gets very complex, most probably still slower than your solution, and one of optimizations might actually use merge by distance at some point...

Comment: @Markus ahh .. sorry..  for: 'you've got', read: 'you would have' (hypothetical).. and we still don't know if it works for OP.. :)

Comment: Cool simple trick!
In my specific case however it didnt work, since I have curves and merge by distance doesnt seem to work on curves. But got there by converting whole mesh to curves (reasons...), so I tried to simply store named attribute for points based on index before converting and that worked like a charm (that named attribute got copied to all disconnected curve points created from original mesh point).
Now Im not sure if I can mark your response as solved, cos its great for most people, but in my case I used something else?

Comment: Hi @JosefLudvíkBöhm !  It looks as if you asked the wrong question, and this is a wrong answer, but they match :)  IMO, the middle of a fix is there, and others can adapt it the way you have, so safe to call it good. ( But i'm biased, of course,)